# Why are there no relevant javascript samples for Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

This article only contains outdated and NOT WORKING samples:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?service=active-directory-b2c&sort=Relevance&platform=javascript

Instead there should be working samples for ReactJS, VueJS and Angular (5+).

I'm always eager to use the latest bits from Microsoft and Azure, so when Azure AD B2C became GA, I adviced my client it was a viable solution to add authentication support to their existing website and mobile app. However, the samples don't (fully) work and are outdated. This has already been provided as feedback as Github issues, but most of these are unanswered: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues
It's also not clear to me whether the problem is MSAL.js or Azure AD B2C, since all samples use MSAL.js and it seems to be the way to go.

I also tried out Auth0 and that experience was the total opposite: great docs, working samples for all most used frameworks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an issue with a sample not working it is best to report that as an issue on the Github sample itself, where the product owners and content authors in Microsoft can respond to it directly and fix the bug. You can even make pull requests directly to these if you would like.

There are several existing JavaScript B2C samples but it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Alternatively, you can leave product feedback in [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) for this.

Stackoverflow is not the ideal place to report this as there is no direct route to the Microsoft content owners from here.

Comment: I was sent here by the azuresupport Twitter account, because the owners do NOT respond to GitHub issues.

Comment: Can you link a Github issue you created? If you have one, I can escalate it to ensure that the content/product owners address it.